# Concisely stack a constant with a Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a concise way to stack a constant with an arbitrary-length `ndarray`?

So far the best I've been able to find are these:

```
b = np.arange(4)

# Pad b with 5:
np.vstack((5 * np.ones_like(b), b))

# Another way:
np.pad(b[np.newaxis, :], ((1,0), (0,0)), 'constant', constant_values=5)
```

The first isn't too bad, but it seems like there should be a way to take advantage of broadcasting. Coming from R, my first instinct was to do something like this:

```
np.vstack( (5, b) ) # similar to R's rbind(5, b)
```

which unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shade more concise and slightly faster:

```
np.vstack(([5]*len(b),b))
```

**A performance comparison:**

```
%%timeit
np.vstack(([5]*len(b),b))

100000 loops, best of 3: 15.8 µs per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
np.vstack((5 * np.ones_like(b), b))

10000 loops, best of 3: 21 µs per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
np.pad(b[np.newaxis, :], ((1,0), (0,0)), 'constant', constant_values=5)

10000 loops, best of 3: 39.6 µs per loop
```

---